# Tethering with same IP address

Tags: windows, tethering

Our university (school) has a limitation that one can only connect to their network using one device per student. It has been put in place because of the poor connectivity here (I'm in South Africa). I have set up my mobile (android) as my connecting device and when I tried to use my laptop on the network by tethering on my mobile I couldn't connect. I'm guessing the IP address is checked and, since the laptop IP is different, it won't let me in. The checking seems to be done via web page (no software needs to be downloaded).

Any idea how I could get the laptop's IP to be the same as the phone? We are instructed to use DHCP and I'm using windows on my laptop.

Comment: doing it the other way would be easier. What sort of phone tho? If you could run a SSH server on the phone, you could tunnel things through that. Its a horrible method, but would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I'm guessing the IP address is checked**

I'm guessing your browser's HTTP headers give you away.

Tethering does not cause your laptop's source address to be any different that that of the phone.

Think of the phone as a virtual Ethernet card (or as a NAT router) as far as the laptop is concerned.

Alternatively, [your phone may use a different APN when tethered](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2011/05/how-does-att-detect-unofficial-iphone-tethering.html)

Answer (score -1):

Easy tethering for android devices that doesn't require root access.
Note that it will install tethering software on your computer in order to get around the root requirement. (Rooting a phone is a whole different process - I'd recommend keeping your phone stock if you aren't technologically savvy.)

Read the description in the link below to grab the software for your PC/mac.
This is a 14 day trial app, after 14 days you must unlock it for $5 in order to get around the 20mB daily data limit. This app was made by ClockworkMod, he is a god in the android development community I'd gladly  give up $5 for this app.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether

Comment: Some Android phones don't need additional software. My HTC Android phone came with tethering as standard, I just plug it into a PC's USB port and choose tethering from a menu that appears on the phone. I didn't have to install or configure software on phone or PC. Does ClockworkMod Tether solve the problem in the question?